# make install workflow workaround in visual studio

Tags: linux, visual-studio, build

Imagine I start working on a fairly big open source C++ project on linux.

I can build it locally and finish install with `sudo make install`.

I want to use Visual Studio and gdb for editing and debugging but I don't feel that 'installing' it on my computer isn't natural in the process of editing - compiling - debugging.

What would be the natural way to achieve this editing loop in Visual Studio ?